# Error when using scipy_leastsquares fitting

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit data to a function using the LM least squares method in scipy. I am trying to find the values of r_s and delta_c. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares


np.seterr(divide='ignore')

def NFW(r, r_s, delta_c):
    
    return np.log10(delta_c * 127.5 / ((r/r_s) * (1+r/r_s)**2))

R = np.array([10., 13.3723382, 17.88194288, 23.91233878, 31.97639691,
              42.75991937, 57.18001031, 76.46304359, 102.24896784, 136.73079658,
              182.84104538, 244.50122949, 326.95533545, 437.21576207, 584.65970352,
              781.82675534, 1045.48522765, 1398.05828227, 1869.53081686, 2500.00000668])

proftot = np.log10([2.86820475e-03, 5.65127564e-04, 2.58072307e-04, 1.19604185e-04,
                    5.72396406e-05, 2.80331317e-05, 1.38935580e-05, 6.87949343e-06,
                    3.33928154e-06, 1.57168352e-06, 7.33896604e-07, 3.09905078e-07,
                    9.48185811e-08, 1.61456370e-08, 1.71789382e-09, 1.69049246e-10,
                    1.67945764e-11, 1.67722875e-12, 3.81870305e-14, 0.00000000e+00])

initial_guess = np.array([5, 50000])

result = least_squares(NFW, initial_guess, method='lm', args=(R, proftot))

print("Optimized Parameters:", result.x)
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
 File x in NFW
    return np.log10(delta_c * 127.5 / ((r/r_s) * (1+r/r_s)**2))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (20,)
```

I think it has something to do with the initial guess but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: If you pass two values in `initial_guess`, then you just pass one value in `args` because your function need three values...

Comment: How many parameters do you need to fit? If you need one, then `initial_guess` must have one element... If you need two, then `initial_guess` must have two elements... and so on...

Comment: What do you expect to go into `delta_c`? It can't be both `R` and `proftot`.

Comment: Rather, it looks like you assume that `R` goes into `r` (which it doesn't), and `r_s` and `delta_c` receive the parameters (which they don't)

Answer (score 0):

At a wild guess, what you actually mean is

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares


def nfw(params: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    r_s, delta_c = params
    r = R
    return np.log10(delta_c * 127.5 /
                    (r/r_s * (1 + r/r_s)**2))


R = np.array([10., 13.3723382, 17.88194288, 23.91233878, 31.97639691,
              42.75991937, 57.18001031, 76.46304359, 102.24896784, 136.73079658,
              182.84104538, 244.50122949, 326.95533545, 437.21576207, 584.65970352,
              781.82675534, 1045.48522765, 1398.05828227, 1869.53081686, 2500.00000668])

result = least_squares(
    fun=nfw,
    x0=(5, 50_000),
    bounds=(0, np.inf),
    max_nfev=500,
)
print(result)
print("Optimized Parameters:", result.x)
```

```
     message: `ftol` termination condition is satisfied.
     success: True
      status: 2
         fun: [ 1.199e+00  1.073e+00 ... -1.073e+00 -1.199e+00]
           x: [ 4.904e+07  2.528e-08]
        cost: 5.296305498423544
         jac: [[ 8.855e-09  1.350e+07]
               [ 8.855e-09  1.350e+07]
               ...
               [ 8.856e-09  1.350e+07]
               [ 8.856e-09  1.350e+07]]
        grad: [-1.505e-11 -1.842e+04]
  optimality: 18422.62083500251
 active_mask: [0 0]
        nfev: 302
        njev: 284
Optimized Parameters: [4.90442086e+07 2.52820701e-08]
```

Your parameters need to be unpacked from the argument passed to the inner function. `proftot` appears unused so delete it. **Do not** disable division warnings; set your bounds.